# Remove any kind of url from string in php?

Tags: php, regex

I am having below data.

Example 1

```
From : http://de.example.ch/biz/barbar-vintage-z%C3%BCrich

I want: /biz/barbar-vintage-z%C3%BCrich
```

And also if there is

```
http://www.example.ch/biz/barbar-vintage-z%C3%BCrich
```

Then 
    I also want

```
 /biz/barbar-vintage-z%C3%BCrich
```

Comment: Have a look at using [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to do this.

Comment: Just run it through [`parse_url()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), I think it's the `path` element you want. You don't need a regular expression.

Comment: No but i have tryout with regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it via regex then you can use:

```
$s = 'http://de.example.ch/biz/barbar-vintage-z%C3%BCrich';
echo preg_replace('~^https?://[^/]+~', '', $s);
//=> /biz/barbar-vintage-z%C3%BCrich
```

Otherwise as the comments says `parse_url` function also let you have this value.

Comment: I'd probably add a start anchor to that regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRelativePath($url)
{
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('#^(http://|https://)([^./]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3}(/.*)$#', $url, $matches) {
        return $matches[3];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match('~^https?://[^/]+\K.+~', $data, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hW9fI7/5)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://de.example.ch/biz/barbar-vintage-z%C3%BCrich';
echo preg_replace('~^https?://[^/]+~', '', $url);
?>
```